# How to implement auto-complete in Angular?

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I need to implement auto-complete in Angular.

I tried this https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview but got below error:

> Error TS2339  (TS) Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Subject<{}>'

Comment: Please share your implemented code.

Comment: Corrected the tags, the title and the question

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code :-

> demo.component.html

```
 <input type="text" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete class="auto-dropdown"#auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits" [value]="fruit">
    {{fruit}}
    </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
```

> demo.component.ts

```
 this.fruits.forEach( fruit => {
             this.listofFruitsArray.push(fruit.fruitName);
          });
          this.demoForm.valueChanges.subscribe(fruit => {
            const { favFruit } = fruit;
              this.filteredFruits = this.filterValues(favFruit);
          });


filterValues(search: string){
         return this.listoFruitsArray.filter( fruit => 
         fruit.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) === 0);
        }
```

> demo.module.ts

```
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';


imports: [
MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
],
```

Hope It will Help Thankyou